# How to run an android device application by inputting values from outside application using python

Tags: python, android, automation

I am working on a module where I need to automate an application in an Android Device using Python. But here is a challenge that I am facing is that the application has visualization part which is a Machine movement. To move the machine, I need to give the inputs from another external application which has fields like North,East,Elevation etc. These values are taken from that external application and Machine gets moved in the android device.

My thoughts are like to use module

```
import subprocess
```

Can some one suggest me if my idea is correct or any other procedures to ahead....I got struck.
Till now no coding has been done and I need to project to convince the team first. We shouldn't use any APIs of the external application.

Comment: can you please explain properly

Comment: There is an application in android which is used to move the machine (animation). To move that Machine from one point to another point (Graphically), we have been using an external software application. In that external application, there are fields like X,Y,Speed etc. If we change these fields, the machine movements can be seen in Android device. Right now, we are modifying the fields manually but what they want us to do is to automate these things.